# Did this example violates the Hollywood principle "dont call us, we call you"

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

Im reader of headfirst design patterns and I noticed this.

"Hollywood principle, dont call us, we call you"

This means high-level component tells low-level component "dont call us, we call you"

High-Level Component is a class with a BEHAVIOR defined with other Low-Level component.

My question is...is this example violates the dont call us, we call you principle?. This is also from the book using State Pattern.

```
public class GumballMachine
{
    //other state instance here

    State NoQuarterState;
    State HasQuarterState;

    public GumballMachine(int numberGumballs)
    {
        NoQuarterState = new NoQuarterState(this);
        HasQuarterState = new HasQuarterState(this);    

        //other state objects here assigning to state instance      
    }

    public void insertQuarter() 
    {   
        state.insertQuarter();  
    }

    void setState(State state) 
    {   
        this.state = state; 
    }

    public State getHasQuarterState() 
    {   
        return hasQuarterState;
    }

    //more code here
}
```

====================================================================

```
public interface State
{
    //abstract methods
}
```

====================================================================

```
public class NoQuarterState implements State
{   
    GumballMachine gumballMachine;

    public NoQuarterState(GumballMachine gumballMachine)
    {
        this.gumballMachine = gumballMachine;
    }

    public void insertQuarter()
    {
        System.out.println("You inserted a quarter");
        gumballMachine.setState(gumballMachine.getHasQuarterState()); // change the state to HasQuarterState
    }
}
```

Because in this example **GumballMachine** needs **NoQuarterState**'s **insertQuarterBehavior()** for its own **insertQuarterBehavior** so this means **GumballMachine** class is the High-Level component and **NoquarterState** class is the Low-level component. But look at the **NoQuarterState** class that class also depends on **gumballMachine's setState()** and **getHasQuarterState()** for it's **insertQuarter() Behavior**.

They depend on each other. C-I-R-C-U-L-A-R - D-E-P-E-N-D-E-N-C-I-E-S

Comment: Yes, I wholeheartedly agree that this is S-H-I-T-T-Y D-E-S-I-G-N all over :) This often happens when the author tries to explain concepts whose point is only evident in massive projects, but on a trivial example like this one. This is way overengineered and the division of labour almost haphazard. One thing weirds me out though: if this is from a book, how come it doesn't respect the ubiquitous java naming convention? Instance fields must follow the lowerCamelCase convention.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I guess it was retyped manually by original poster. Here's the original version from the book: http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/cocchi/CMP346/state/GumballMachine.java

Comment: I see. Well, in that code the design mistakes have not been committed yet. It's all the doing of the poster you mention. The `State` objects should **return** the new state, not set it directly on the parent object. That's where the design goes astray. It's fixable.

Comment: BTW for me personally the huge waste of screen realestate caused by such sparse formatting style hurts readabilty of the code. Especially when such trivial code as getter/setter is involved. There is ZERO information in those lines of code and it forces you to run around with your scrollwheel trying to find any real code.

Comment: @Marko: I thought the same thing at first. However, how would a state return the new state without either creating it (thus becoming responsible for its lifecycle which you don't want), receiving it (thus forcing the GumballMachine to pass states around and possible having to know which state needs which successor states) or accessing it via a static reference (bad practice and circumventing the purpose of the pattern)?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Didn't bother to think it through, but it sounds to me that the machine-driving component definitely should keep track of the current state and ask that object for the next state. If the state returns a new state, it doesn't automatically become responsible for its lifecycle. There isn't much to the state's lifecycle, anyway. Once it's no longer referenced, it goes away. The driving object doesn't need to know in advance what successor states are possible, each state knows that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should read about the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).
What you posted is a rather simple version of it. In the code you posted, the only time `new` is called is in the `Gumball` machine, which actually is not bad since the ***states*** are associated/belong to the `Gumball` machine and would be the central and only place to instantiate them. It would also the only place to add/remove them. So instantiation of concrete classes are in a single place in code.

The `NoQuarterState` is `associated` with the `Gumball` machine (and any other `State` for this matter) and this makes sence since only the `NoQuarterState` knows which would be the next correct state to follow after its processing, effectively making `Gumball` into a box moving depending on the results of each state. This way the `Gumball` can change `State` without knowing how or under what conditions one state follows the other. This is encapsulated in the `State` concrete instances.

And as a matter of fact the `Gumball` only knows of `States` in its various `getters` and `setters` in your code. And the only methods that it calls are those that belong to `State` and not to `NoQuarterState` etc.
So although this is a rather simplified example that could be improved (BTW do not think it is allowed to copy-paste an example out of a book), it does not violate the principle you ask about per se, `Holywood` principle's core idea is about loose coopling and this code does not violate it IMHO

Comment: Of course the example does violate the principle of loose coupling! Sometimes authors sacrifice perfection in favor of simplicity.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster:Eventually, now matter how loose-coopled is your system, some one has to call `new`.How much this instantiation is under control, in a centralized location is what makes the difference.I undertand what you are trying to say though.But I think the author can make his point despite the simplification of his example

Answer (score 1):

You should see the GumballMachine as the context within which the States operate. This pattern REQUIRES the States to be able to get a reference to any other State and to change the current State. This means the tight coupling is intended here, allowing the GumballMachine to be agnostic of State-level logic but responsible for the lifecycle of the states and their shared point of reference.

Principles and patterns are not the ultimate goal of a design effort. In the end you have to come up with a fitting solution for the problem at hand and sometimes certain patterns and principles do not apply. Having said that, if you notice that you are really violating an important principle (like loose coupling/tight cohesion) that is a sign that something may be wrong and you should at least ask yourself why it is the case and if it can be avoided within the constraints of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does violate the Hollywood Principle, for exactly the reasons you pointed out. But as the same book emphasizes, the principles are not laws and are often violated. For example, callbacks are a common and useful violation of the Hollywood Principle.